# Is it possible to show a repo on Github's profile with all commits being a contributor?

Tags: github, share

We are a team and we have a repo on Github. I am one of the contributors, now the repo is almost finished and has several commits, but being a contributor this repo isn't visible on my profile's repos section .

Is there a way to show this repo on my profile in agreement with repo's owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pin the repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile) to your profile, in `Your profile > Customize your pins`.

Any public repository you have contributed to can be pinned. You can also pin repositories where you have opened issues, reviewed PRs, etc. The full criteria can be found [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#contributions-that-are-counted).